# How to pass input value data to root element in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to achieve data transfer from component to root element in Vue.
I am trying to access the 'title' value from root element with method.
When the code is executed, the console throws me 'undefined' instead of 'title' value.
Is it even possible with my idea?

```
var app = Vue.createApp({
    props: ['handle'],
    components: ['custom-form'],
    methods: {
        showData: function() {
            console.log (this.handle)
            return this.handle
        }
    },
    created() {
        console.log (this.showData())
    }
})

app.component ('custom-form', {
    props: ['value'],
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <input type="text" v-model="inputValue" />
    `,
    data(){
        return {
            title: 'login'
        }
    },
    computed:{
        inputValue:{
            get(){ this.title },
            set(v){ this.$emit('update:inputValue',v) }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handle(){
            return this.inputValue
        } 
    }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: try using `eventBus` or `vuex store`

Comment: see: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/v-model.html basically `props: ['value'],` would now be `props: ['modelValue'],` and `get(){ this.title },` would be `get() { return this.modelValue },` example https://playcode.io/826186/

Comment: np, I thought id expand the example. passing things around can be tricky at first but once you get it, it's pretty simple. if you're going to have multiple nested things or the parent has a bunch of children and the children need to be accessing things in siblings then look into vuex, avoid global event buses as that's a hack for not using vuex, if vuex is too much, you can always just use a mixin which contains a data which is an [observable](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state)

Comment: After spending some days of struggling to understand Vue coding with you and other good helping hands in SO I came with result like this: https://jsfiddle.net/e2mnh4xa/